# Getting double result from abs(double) instead of int

Tags: c++

I need to calculate the absolute value of a difference of two `double` values and have a `double` result. Instead, I'm getting an `int`.

```
#include <typeinfo>
// ...
printf(
    "a:%s b:%s delta:%s abs:%s\n",
    typeid(a).name(),
    typeid(b).name(),
    typeid(a - b).name(),
    typeid(abs(a - b)).name()
);
// Prints: a:d b:d delta:d abs:i
```

If the result of the subtraction is already a double, why is `abs` not using the [`double abs (double x);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/) signature? Indeed, how can it be returning an integer at all? Most importantly, how do I force it to return a `double`?

<sub>*In case it makes a difference, `a` and `b` are actually `myData.m_lat` and `otherData.latitude()`.*</sub>

Comment: No way of knowing what `abs` function you're calling. [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid clashes with unintentionally imported C standard library headers, use `std::abs` instead. That's the C++ version, and is heavily overloaded, as you already know.

Otherwise use `fabs` from the C standard library.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. :) Indeed, I did not already know. Except for the last two weeks, I last programmed in C++ in 1994. :)

Comment: I would also suggest building with ``-Wconversion`` to avoid similar problems

Comment: Compiling with icc doesn't do this for me. I get:
`error: no instance of overloaded function "std::max" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int, double)
      double value      = std::max(std::abs(thisPoint), lowerLimit);` 
For me `thisPoint` is a double

Answer (score 3):

Prior to C++17 `abs` for [floating points](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) and for [integrals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) were defined in different headers (`cmath` and `cstdlib` respectively).

Comment: I have no idea how it was in 2016, but it seems like now they're defined in both `cmath` and `cstdlib`(so just #include only one header would be enough, I guess?) according to cppreference.com, but cppreference.com's _webpages are still separated_ for floating-points and integers so that could be a little confusing for a novice.